# Integrate Nutch with Solr For Advance Search Options

Tags: solr, nutch

I am using **apache-nutch-1.4** with **apache-solr-3.2.0**

I have successfully integrated **NUTCH** with **SOLR**

when i have queried the following

mysite/solr/select/?q=bone&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on

It gives me following result

```
<doc>
<float name="boost">1.0117649</float>
<str name="cache">content</str>
<str name="content"></str>
<str name="digest">9bf016ea547cf50be81e468553c483de</str>
<str name="id">http://107.21.107.118:8000/</str>
<str name="segment">20120214151903</str>
<str name="title">Home</str>
<date name="tstamp">2012-02-14T10:19:08.215Z</date>
<str name="url">mysite:8000/</str>
</doc>
```

Problem is when i have to search bone in particular category like **cancer** or **Colorectal & Digestive**

then what **param** i need to add in above query to get records for this specific category only

mysite:8983/solr/select/?q=bone&????????

i have urls like

mysite:8000/Encyclopedia/Patient Centers/

mysite:8000/Encyclopedia/Patient Centers/Cancer/

mysite:8000/Encyclopedia/Patient Centers/Cancer/Colorectal & Digestive/

my **schema.xml** file looks like this which i have added in **NUTCH** directory also....

http://dpaste.org/MTDF2/

my reputation is not 10 so i can not make any attachment here thats why i needed to paste schema.xml on dpaste.org...

sorry for the inconvenience it may have caused.

i will realy apreciate your advice and sugessions ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to store Cancer and Colorectal & Digestive in a category field. You can use http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.PathHierarchyTokenizerFactory for that. Then 
the URL's could look like mysite:8983/solr/select/?q=bone&fq=category:Cancer

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#fq